# gitleaks not working in spring boot project

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, gitleaks

In my .pre-commit-config.yaml file I have this :

```html
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks
    rev: v8.17.0
    hooks:
      - id: gitleaks
        args:
          - detect
```

In one of my child project of spring boot application I have this secret:

```html
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      access-key: ASIAT444444444444
      secret-key: aCGuxeQMe222222222222222222
```

and still when I commit my changes , it gives me no error

```html
    $ git commit -m "check6"
Detect hardcoded secrets.................................................Passed
[develop 23c86f88] check6
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

I followed pre-commit section from this documentation
[gitleaks](https://github.com/gitleaks/gitleaks/tree/master)